# How do you do a map within a map through an array for only certain items?

Tags: reactjs

So far the map is working perfectly except for one problem, every time I click the button to post a comment a whole new post populates the UI. What I want is to only render a comment not a whole post every time I click the post comment button. What I tried to do is do map within a map, as you can see below. However its still rendering the a whole post. How do I map for a certain item, I think that will help. What should I do?

```
const { TextArea } = Input;


const PostOnWall = (props) => (
    <div>
        {props.postInfo.map( (item) => (
            <div>
                <div className="PostOnWall">
                        <div className="topbar">
                            <img src = {profile} className="image"/>
                            <div className="name">Brad Pitt</div>
                            <div>{item.time}</div>
                        </div>
                    <div className="text">{item.post}</div>
                    <img src={item.uploadedImage} />

                </div>
                <div className="engagementBar">
                    <div><FontAwesomeIcon  icon={fathumbsup} size="2x"/> Like</div>
                    <div><FontAwesomeIcon  icon={facomment} size="2x"/> Comment</div>
                    <div><FontAwesomeIcon  icon={fasharesquare} size="2x"/> Share</div>
                </div>
                <div className="postCommentBox">
                <img src = {profile} className="image"/>
                <TextArea type = "text" placeholder="Write a comment" autoSize id="comment" onChange={props.onChange}/>
                <div>    
                    <button onClick={props.onClick}></button>
                </div>                
                </div>
                {item.comment.map( (items) => (
                <div>
                    <div> {items} </div>
                </div>
                ))
            }

    </div>
    ))
    }

    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with current structure it's not really possible to re-render only comments. In order to make that possible you might need to move comments to a separate component.

Another important thing I spot you don't use `key` while rendering lists, so it decreases performance quite a lot as React will need to re-render the whole list on each render. You can read about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html